# Image does not remain same size when window is resized- twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, image, hover

Hey Guys I am using twitter bootstrap for a website along with this jquery script:

```
$('.fadein').each(function() {

var std = $(this).attr("src");
var hover = std.replace("img/flyoutcricket-noglow.jpg", "img/flyoutcricket-glow.jpg"); 
$(this).clone().insertAfter(this).attr('src', hover).removeClass('fadein').siblings().css({
    position:'absolute'
});
$(this).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(700, 0);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(700, 1);
});
```

});

The trouble I am having is when resizing the responsive web page.  The images do not remain the same size in smaller windows.  (tablet, mobile, etc.)  Any ideas?

the webiste is flyoutcricket.com.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what should happen? I just tested your site and it all seemed to work as it should.

Comment: Try resizing window.  It works when screen is full but not when screen is resized to be small.  Images are two different sizes.

Comment: I see the image changing size, and that's what they're supposed to be doing. Could you upload a screenshot to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) with the problem area circled or something?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/70z5tl/5  The images sizes are outlined in blue and red.  For some reason they do not remain the same size in smaller window sizes or mobile.  The behind image is the correct size.  Thank you guys for all the help. :-)

Comment: red outline is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This is the CSS for img from bootstrap.  The image is always going to be sized at 100% of the width of its containing block, with the height keeping in proportion.  But this is not the case when the image is absolutely positioned and the containing element is statically positioned.

So change your CSS so that the containing element for those images is not statically positioned:

```
.chapter1 {
    border: 30px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

EDIT:
Bad explanation on my part of bootstrap's rule for img.

This is better:

> Instead of just rendering at its native width and overflowing its containing box, the image would render at its native dimensions as long as its width didn’t exceed the width of its container.

from: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/

Comment: !! Thank you so much!  I am kind of just starting out in the web world.  I really appreciate this!

Comment: @TomBurden - I hope you find it to be very rewarding.  Anytime you encounter an element that is not being sized or positioned where you think it should be, checking whether or not the containing element is statically positioned (the default if no position is defined) is a good place to start.  Have fun!

Comment: I spent 3 days on this.  I thought I may of needed a jquery resize script but the problem was a lot simpler.  Thank you.